# relevel factors and reorder factors using tidyverse in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I want to use the functions ***relevel()*** and ***reorder()*** in my data frame. I understand how relevel works, but I do NOT understand why I do not see the change in the levels in my data.frame. For example, imagine that I have the iris dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)

head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa


iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, levels = c("versicolor","setosa","virginica"), 
                       labels = c("versicolor","setosa","virginica"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I can use this function to change the order of the levels
or this function in dplyr :

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species=factor(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(Species=fct_relevel(Species,c("versicolor","setosa","virginica"))) %>% 
  head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
What I do not get is that while I see the change in the levels in my data set, when i call my data set i do not see the change of the order, which is essential to me.
This is what I see

```
Species
setosa
...
versicolor
...
virginica
...
```

This is what i want to see

```
Species
versicolor
...
setosa
...
virginica
...
```

Any help to change the order with Tidyverse is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We need to assign back to make the changes in the original data.  In addition to changing the order of `levels`, we may need to `arrange` the data if the rows order needs to be changed as well

```
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species=factor(Species)) %>% 
  mutate(Species=fct_relevel(Species,c("versicolor","setosa","virginica"))) %>%
 arrange(Species)
```

---

Or may use the assignment operator (`%<>%`) from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
iris %<>% 
  mutate(Species=factor(Species)) %<>% 
  mutate(Species=fct_relevel(Species,c("versicolor","setosa","virginica")))%>%
  arrange(Species)
```

check the `levels`

```
levels(iris$Species)
[1] "versicolor" "setosa"     "virginica"
```

Comment: Hello akrun, thank for your answer. I really appreciate. Yes I still see the change of the levels but the order of species remain the same. I am uploading a screenshot in the question. Sorry i might be wrong

Comment: @LDT For that you need `arrange`  I was thinking that you need to change only `levels`

Comment: can I arrange using a the order I like?